# Can KeePass 2.x HTML exports be fully automated?

Tags: automation, export, keepass

The password management tool KeePass 2.x allows for customized HTML exports via *File > Export > Customizable HTML File*. There, file path and most importantly the desired database fields can be specified in the export dialog.

Also, KeePass comes with a built-in trigger system, via *Tools > Triggers...*. For instance, a trigger for the "Saved database file" event can be defined along with the action "Export active database". This way, exports can be automated.

Now assume that we want to export the entire database in **HTML format without passwords** every time the database file is saved.

The trigger system can be used to define an export with file format "Customizable HTML File", however, this will pop-up the HTML export customization dialog every time the action is triggered. Manual user intervention is required -- the export is not fully automated.

On the other hand, formats like *KeePass XML (2.x)* can also be specified as the desired export format, however, those formats -- which do not require manual action -- all include the unencrypted password and cannot be used without further processing (password removal, conversion to human-readable format like HTML).

Is there a way to automate a HTML export without the password field using built-in KeePass functionality only?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

According to a post in the official KeePass discussion forum, the trigger and export system can't be used that way:

> I can't see a way to do it with existing controls.
>
> You may be able to write a plug-in to do it.

http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/151706fa/